# Cyclic Redundancy Check comparison has different values

Tags: python, sockets, udp, crc, crc32

There are 3 codes that need to do the following actions:

- A sends a message to B along with the CRC32 code.
- B receives this message and CRC32 code.
- B follows a 40% probability to change the message.
- B sends the message along with the original CRC32 code to C.
- C receives the message and CRC32 code and check whether it is correct or not.

For some reason, in part C when I compare the CRC's they are never equal, what am I missing?

Part A:

```
import socket
import struct
import sys
import binascii

def crc32(v):
     r = binascii.crc32(v.encode())
     return r


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <ip> <liseten port>")
    sys.exit(-1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    print("Input text:")
    text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    ss = struct.pack("!50sL",text.encode(),crc32(text))
    s.sendto(ss,(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2])))
    if text == "bye":
        break
```

Part B:

```
import socket
import operator
import sys
import binascii
import struct
import random

def crc32(v):
    return binascii.crc32(v.encode())

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <liseten port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))
print("Waiting...")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    str,crc = struct.unpack("!50sL",data)
    str = str.decode("utf-8").replace("\0","")
    if random.randint(0,100) < 40:
        str = str + "x"
    print("str:%s\ncrc:%X" % (str,crc & 0xffffffff))
    str2 = str.encode("utf-8")
    tpack = struct.pack("!50sL", str2, crc)
    s.sendto(tpack,("127.0.0.1",int(sys.argv[2])))

    if str == "bye":
        break
```

Part C:

```
import socket
import operator
import sys
import binascii
import struct

def crc32(v):
    return binascii.crc32(v.encode())

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Useage: python " + sys.argv[0] + " <liseten port>")
    sys.exit(-1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", int(sys.argv[1])))
print("Waiting...")
while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    str,crc = struct.unpack("!50sL",data)
    str = str.decode("utf-8")
    print("str:%s\ncrc:%X" % (str,crc & 0xffffffff))

    ncrc = crc32(str)
    if ncrc == crc:
        print("both messages are the same")
    if str == "bye":
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to replace the null bytes in Part C.  You calculated the CRC in Part A before packing to 50 bytes, and removed them in Part B when displaying the received value.

```
str = str.decode("utf-8")
```

should b:

```
str = str.decode("utf-8").replace('\0','')
```

Note: `str` is a builtin function that you lose access to by using it as a variable name.

Comment: Thank you so very much, that did indeed solve the issue.